# Paste text at the end of the line with a space between in vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to find a the fastest way to paste text at the end of the line, but with a space between the previous EOL and new text. The current method is `a <ESC>p` or `o<ESC>pkJ`. Is there any other, faster way to achive this? I'm thinking about something like "paste with offset"?

```
Original: The quick brown fox 
after $p: The quick brown foxjumps over the lazy dog
desired : The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a map which is based on Mark's answer but seems to suit what you want more closely:

```
:nnoremap 1 A <esc>p
```

You can pick any key or combination instead of `1`.

Comment: This solution is surely more universal, maybe what I want is unreachable without a key maping.

Comment: @Sebastian I don't see why you'd want to avoid a key mapping. They are probably the main part of vim's awesomeness.

Comment: I believed that what I want is achievable without another key mapping, there are so many of them to remember already and I wanted to avoid redundancy.

Comment: @Sebastian You're not supposed to _remember_ all the key mappings you do (as opposed to standard vim commands). You're supposed to make them once (in the most natural way you can think of), save them in your `vimrc` and from then on just use them. You can easily set this command for the `$p` sequence, for example.

Comment: What I meant was to remember another key combination, obviously I don't map each of my own mappings each time I run vim ;]

Answer (score 14):

If you do not want to use a mapping, you can type <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>.

See `:h i_ctrl-r` for more information.  This is what is happening:

```
A        Append text to end of line (enters insert mode).
space  - Actual space key to insert a space.
ctrl+r - Insert contents of a register.
"      - Default register of yank and paste.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This this uses exactly the same amount of keystrokes as `a <ESC>p`, but leaves us in insert mode. +1 for bringing ctrl+r up - that combination is extremely useful. I think I'll stick to the key mapping though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
:map 1 A your text to append.
```

then hit the "1" key.

This will map the "1" key as a shortcut to the command "A" (which appends to end of current line).

Comment: I think this approach unfortunately requires many keystrokes more than the `a <ESC>p` method I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Only the first time. Then it's one per line.

Comment: ok, this can be useful but only when you want to paste the same text many times.

Comment: I presume you want to do it many times, else you wouldn't be bothered how long it took, surely?

Comment: The main reason for my question was to decrease the time of such an operation, mainly while pasting not repetitive pieces of text. This solution is helpful, but I'm not sure if it isn't easier to create a macro - the result is the same, you don't have to map the key and you can repeat the macro without moving to each line.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable `mswin` behavior, `Ctrl-v` pastes text.  Therefore, the key sequence would from command mode, `A` to get into insert mode at end of line, `<space>` to insert a space, then `Ctrl-v` to paste.

Alternatively, while in insert mode, use the mouse to put the cursor at the end of a line, `<space>` then `Ctrl-v`.

However, `Ctrl-v` accesses the system clipboard, so you have to make yank operations copy to the system clipboard, on Windows this is `:set clipboard=unnamed`.

Stick this in your `.vimrc`:

```
" enable Windows-style key bindings
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin

" yank to system clipboard
set clipboard=unnamed
```